# Pivot like sort - SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table (books) that like this:

```
user_rent | book_rent | rent_from  | rent_to
-----------------------------------------------
Alan Doe  | Macbeth   | 01.07.2018 | 15.07.2018
Alan Doe  | Hamlet    | 16.07.2018 | 01.08.2018
Alan Doe  | Othello   | 02.08.2018 | 31.08.2018
Alan Doe  | King Lear | 01.09.2018 |    
Alex Doe  | Dracula   | 01.07.2018 | 15.07.2018
Alex Doe  | Hamlet    | 16.07.2018 | 01.08.2018
Alex Doe  | Hobbit    | 02.08.2018 | 31.08.2018
Alex Doe  | Inferno   | 01.09.2018 |    
Anna Doe  | 1984      | 01.07.2018 | 15.07.2018
Anna Doe  | King Lear | 16.07.2018 | 01.08.2018
Anna Doe  | Hobbit    | 02.08.2018 | 31.08.2018
Anna Doe  | Dracula   | 01.09.2018 |    
Ella Doe  | Macbeth   | 01.07.2018 | 15.07.2018
Ella Doe  | Beowulf   | 16.07.2018 | 01.08.2018
Ella Doe  | King Lear | 02.08.2018 | 31.08.2018
Ella Doe  | Dracula   | 01.09.2018 |    
Emma Doe  | Beowulf   | 01.07.2018 | 15.07.2018
Emma Doe  | Inferno   | 16.07.2018 | 01.08.2018
Emma Doe  | Macbeth   | 02.08.2018 | 31.08.2018
Emma Doe  | Lolita    | 01.09.2018 |    
Jack Doe  | 1984      | 01.07.2018 | 15.07.2018
Jack Doe  | Inferno   | 16.07.2018 | 01.08.2018
Jack Doe  | Othello   | 02.08.2018 | 31.08.2018
Jack Doe  | Dracula   | 01.09.2018 |
Jade Doe  | Lolita    | 01.07.2018 | 15.07.2018
Jade Doe  | Hobbit    | 16.07.2018 | 01.08.2018
Jade Doe  | Hamlet    | 02.08.2018 | 31.08.2018
Jade Doe  | Beowulf   | 01.09.2018 |    
Jane Doe  | Dracula   | 01.07.2018 | 15.07.2018
Jane Doe  | Ulysses   | 16.07.2018 | 01.08.2018
Jane Doe  | Inferno   | 02.08.2018 | 31.08.2018
Jane Doe  | Pygmalion | 01.09.2018 |
John Doe  | Macbeth   | 01.07.2018 | 15.07.2018
John Doe  | Hobbit    | 16.07.2018 | 01.08.2018
John Doe  | Ulysses   | 02.08.2018 | 31.08.2018
John Doe  | Dracula   | 01.09.2018 |    
Noah Doe  | Pygmalion | 01.07.2018 | 15.07.2018
Noah Doe  | Othello   | 16.07.2018 | 01.08.2018
Noah Doe  | Beowulf   | 02.08.2018 | 31.08.2018
Noah Doe  | 1984      | 01.09.2018 |    
Nora Doe  | Dracula   | 01.07.2018 | 15.07.2018
Nora Doe  | Pygmalion | 16.07.2018 | 01.08.2018
Nora Doe  | Hamlet    | 02.08.2018 | 31.08.2018
Nora Doe  | Lolita    | 01.09.2018 |    
Sara Doe  | Beowulf   | 01.07.2018 | 15.07.2018
Sara Doe  | Dracula   | 16.07.2018 | 01.08.2018
Sara Doe  | Ulysses   | 02.08.2018 | 31.08.2018
Sara Doe  | Lolita    | 01.09.2018 |    
Seth Doe  | Macbeth   | 01.07.2018 | 15.07.2018
Seth Doe  | Hamlet    | 16.07.2018 | 01.08.2018
Seth Doe  | King Lear | 02.08.2018 | 31.08.2018
Seth Doe  | Othello   | 01.09.2018 |
```

I need a number of users who rented Shakespeare's books.

With this query:

```
SELECT USER_RENT,
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BOOK_RENT = 'Hamlet' THEN USER_RENT END) HAMLET,
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BOOK_RENT = 'Othello' THEN USER_RENT END) OTHELLO,
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BOOK_RENT = 'Macbeth' THEN USER_RENT END) MACBETH,
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BOOK_RENT = 'King Lear' THEN USER_RENT END) KING_LEAR
FROM BOOKS
GROUP BY USER_RENT;
```

I got this temporary table:

```
user_rent | hamlet | othello | macbeth | king_lear
--------------------------------------------------
Alan Doe  |      1 |       1 |       1 |       1
Alex Doe  |      1 |       0 |       0 |       0
Anna Doe  |      0 |       0 |       0 |       1
Ella Doe  |      0 |       0 |       1 |       1
Emma Doe  |      0 |       0 |       1 |       0
Jack Doe  |      0 |       1 |       0 |       0
Jade Doe  |      1 |       0 |       0 |       0
Jane Doe  |      0 |       0 |       0 |       0
John Doe  |      0 |       0 |       1 |       0
Noah Doe  |      0 |       1 |       0 |       0
Nora Doe  |      1 |       0 |       0 |       0
Sara Doe  |      0 |       0 |       0 |       0
Seth Doe  |      1 |       1 |       1 |       1
```

which I exported to excel and then via pivot and filters got my final wanted result (**this is what I need**):

```
book_rent                  | number
-----------------------------------
Hamlet                     | 5
Othello                    | 4
Macbeth                    | 5
King Lear                  | 4
Hamlet AND Othello         | 2
Hamlet AND Macbeth         | 2
Hamlet AND King Lear       | 2
Othello AND Macbeth        | 1
Othello AND King Lear      | 2
Macbeth AND King Lear      | 3
H AND O AND M              | 2
H AND O AND K              | 2
H AND M AND K              | 2
O AND M AND K              | 2
All four                   | 2
Hamlet OR Othello          | 7
Hamlet OR Macbeth          | 8
.
.
.
```

Since I have much bigger table then this made for this example, is there a more elegant and easy way to do this directly in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT books, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT USER_RENT, LISTAGG(BOOK_RENT, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY BOOK_RENT) as books
      FROM BOOKS
      GROUP BY USER_RENT
     ) bu
GROUP BY books;
```

If someone rents the same book twice, it appears multiple times.  You may want:

```
SELECT books, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT USER_RENT, LISTAGG(BOOK_RENT, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY BOOK_RENT) as books
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT USER_RENT, BOOK_RENT FROM BOOKS) ub
      GROUP BY USER_RENT
     ) bu
GROUP BY books;
```

Comment: I included my whole example table, because this does not work as I need.
I need a table at the bottom of my question. Number of users who have any Shakespeare books with various variants (1 book, 2 books, 3 books, 4 books).
Listagg is something that looks useful, I might have to play with this.

Comment: @Tzereen . . . That is what this query does.  This shows each group of books and the number of users with that combination.

Comment: I understand, but that's not what I need. 
The last part of my question contains the desired output, which I got manually with excel. I'd like to get that with SQL query.

Comment: @Tzereen . . . What is the difference?  The `AND` versus `;`?  You might want to set up a rextester or dbfiddle for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt:

```
/* -- sample data 
with titles(book) as (
  select 'Hamlet'    from dual union all
  select 'Othello'   from dual union all
  select 'Macbeth'   from dual union all
  select 'King Lear' from dual ),
books (usr, book) as (
  select 'Alan', 'Hamlet'    from dual union all
  select 'Alan', 'Othello'   from dual union all
  select 'Alan', 'Macbeth'   from dual union all
  select 'Alan', 'King Lear' from dual union all
  select 'Alan', 'Hamlet'    from dual union all
  select 'Alex', 'Hamlet'    from dual union all
  select 'Anna', 'King Lear' from dual union all
  select 'Ella', 'Macbeth'   from dual union all
  select 'Ella', 'King Lear' from dual union all
  select 'Emma', 'Macbeth'   from dual union all
  select 'Jack', 'Othello'   from dual union all
  select 'Jade', 'Hamlet'    from dual union all
  select 'John', 'Macbeth'   from dual union all
  select 'Noah', 'Othello'   from dual union all
  select 'Nora', 'Hamlet'    from dual union all
  select 'Seth', 'Hamlet'    from dual union all
  select 'Seth', 'Othello'   from dual union all
  select 'Seth', 'Macbeth'   from dual union all
  select 'Seth', 'King Lear' from dual ),
*/ -- end of sample data
with 
  tmp as (
    select grp, sys_connect_by_path(book, '#') path, level cnt
      from (select row_number() over (order by book) grp, book from titles) 
      connect by book > prior book),
  groups as (
    select grp, path, cnt, trim(column_value) book 
      from tmp, xmltable(('"'||replace(ltrim(path,'#'), '#', '","')||'"')))
select path, count(1) cnt, listagg(usr, ', ') within group (order by usr) users
  from (
    select usr, path, grp
      from groups g join (select distinct usr, book from books) b on b.book = g.book
      group by usr, path, cnt, grp
      having cnt = count(1))
  group by path
```

It seems you want all combinations of groups of books. I used hierarchical query and then splitted result of function `sys_connect_by_path()` into rows to achieve this.

Next step is to join these groups with table `books`, count number of books for each user and if this number is lower than number of books in group - remove him from result.

At the end I only group users to count them and present in list form. Result:

```
PATH                                      CNT USERS
---------------------------------- ---------- -------------------------------
#Hamlet                                     5 Alan, Alex, Jade, Nora, Seth
#Hamlet#King Lear                           2 Alan, Seth
#Hamlet#King Lear#Macbeth                   2 Alan, Seth
#Hamlet#King Lear#Macbeth#Othello           2 Alan, Seth
#Hamlet#King Lear#Othello                   2 Alan, Seth
#Hamlet#Macbeth                             2 Alan, Seth
#Hamlet#Macbeth#Othello                     2 Alan, Seth
#Hamlet#Othello                             2 Alan, Seth
#King Lear                                  4 Alan, Anna, Ella, Seth
#King Lear#Macbeth                          3 Alan, Ella, Seth
#King Lear#Macbeth#Othello                  2 Alan, Seth
#King Lear#Othello                          2 Alan, Seth
#Macbeth                                    5 Alan, Ella, Emma, John, Seth
#Macbeth#Othello                            2 Alan, Seth
#Othello                                    4 Alan, Jack, Noah, Seth
```